# In Codeigniter when insert data in db alert message is not displaying, directly it is redirecting

Tags: codeigniter, alert

i am using codigniter .when i am inserting or updating data in mysqldb data is inserting.my form is in popup.then alert is getting but redirecting was not working..issue is redirected is displaying in popup not to page .can you please tell the alternate solution ..i am using ajax update to my form

This is my code of controller

```
    $testid=$this->objTests->updateTest();
    echo "<script> alert('sucessfully updated');</script>"
    redirect(base_url().'tests');
```

this is my following code of model:

```
$testData = array('simulationId'  => $this->input-   >post('simulationId'),
                  'testTitle'     => $this->input->post('testTitle'),
                  'description '  => $this->input->post('description')           
            );
    $this->db->where('id',$this->input->post('tid'));
    $this->db->update('tests',$testData);
    return $this->input->post('tid');
```

Comment: insufficient info pls provide your conroller method and ajax so that we can configure what is actually happening there

Comment: you are not using the right way, first of all you must get form data in `controller`, not in `Model`.. and the next thing is if you want to alert then you must do it using `AJAX`, or in codeigniter you must use `$this->session->set_flashdata('sucess'_message,'success' )` and print this msg on your view.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
  $( "#frmActiontest" ).submit(function( event ) {
     var url = $(this).attr('action');
          $.ajax({
          url: url,
          data: $("#frmActiontest").serialize(),
          type: $(this).attr('method')
        }).done(function(data) {
          //window.location.href="http://neuronguru.com/MedAdmin/tests/";
          window.location.reload();
          /*$('#result').html(data);
          $('#frmActiontest')[0].reset();*/
        });
      event.preventDefault();
  });
  $( ".test" ).on("click",function(event) {
        var url = $(this).data('url');
        var actionUrl = $(this).data('actionurl');
        console.log(actionUrl);
        $("#frmActiontest").attr('action',actionUrl);
        $.ajax({
          url: url,
          type: "GET",
          dataType: 'json'
        }).done(function(data) {
          data=data[0];
          $("#myModalTestLabel").html("Update Test");
          $("#simulationId").val(data.simulationId);
          $("#testTitle").val(data.testTitle);
          $("#description").val(data.description);
          //$("#contents").val(data.contents);
          $("#tid").val(data.id);
          $("#testModal").trigger("click");
          console.log(data);
        });
      event.preventDefault();
  });
  });



  this is my ajax function for the  above question
```